# Should I end my PHP script with exit or exit;?

Tags: php

Today I have a little weird question.
Should I end my PHP script with exit or exit; and which is correct?.

**Without ;**

[image]

and

**With ;**

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: With ";". Like everything in PHP

Comment: If anything exists that you should do is remove `?>` from the end of your script. Why are you `exit;`-ing anyway? What does `exit` solve in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exit`, `exit;`, `exit()`, and `exit();` are exactly the same, but the fact is that you should **not** end your script with an exit() call, it's just bad practice (but it works).

**EDIT**

Clarifying why i said it's "bad practice", it's not about the functionality of "exit" itself, it's OK to halt the script execution if something bad happens, but the concept of "something bad" is really wide. In general, even if some unwanted condition occurs, the normal execution flow should reach to the end of the file. Just consider this example:

```
...some init stuff...
if (!user_is_authenticated) {
   ...print some nasty message...
   exit();
}
...continue with normal stuff...
```

A better approach would be:

```
...some init stuff...
if (user_is_authenticated) {
   ...continue with normal stuff...
}
else {
   ...print some nasty message...
}
```

What's the difference? The difference is that in the second version you don't need to use exit(), which means if one day you need to do something after BOTH the "normal" and "unwanted" execution flows you can just add it at the end of the file.

It's more or less the same argument about why you should NOT use "return" in function bodies except at the end of the function..

Comment: Could you explain why it's bad practice?

Comment: sure, check updated answer

Comment: That is not a bad practice necessarily, it depends a lot on the case and coding style. Doing early returns to exit when a condition is not met is a perfectly valid way to avoid too much nesting in some cases.

Comment: When using PHP within a framework, like laravel or yii or wordpress, then it certainly is bad practice because you are normally part of a larger process and although you can echo results and exit to return some content, it normally is best done within returning data.  If this is a command line script then exit statements along with a useful status code are critical to creating useful scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It is allways a good practise to use `semicolon`

```
<?php

//exit program normally
exit;
exit();
exit(0);

//exit with an error code
exit(1);
exit(0376); //octal

?>
```

Comment: I got confused when my friend told me I should use exit instead of exit; .
Thanks :-D

Comment: Exit isn't a function. It's a language construct.

Answer (score 0):

Like Johnny said, all those four forms of 'exit' statement work. Both `exit` and `exit()` work if there is no statements followed by any of these two language constructs. It doesn't work if there is any other PHP statements followed by these two constructs and semicolon's purpose is to end the statement to proceed to the next statement, therefore you need to use `exit;` or `exit();` to avoid syntax error and also, in this case, without using semicolon is considered to be a bad practice in the coding conventions.